# Source for Tashlumin On Pesach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, korban, tashlumin, shalosh-regalim

The Gemara in Chagigah 9a (according to Rashi and Steinsaltz) derives by Gezeira Shavah from Pesach that you can bring tashlumin for the first day of Sukkot the whole holiday.

In Chagigah 17a and Rosh Hashanah 4b the Gemara derives by hekeish to Pesach that you can bring tashlumin for the first day of Shavuot for seven days as well.

From where do we learn though that there is Tashlumin for the chagigah/reiyah on pesach?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand the Gemara on 9a. We’re not learning Sukkos from Pesach, but rather Pesach from Sukkos.  The translation that follows is how I understood the Gemara.

> נאמר עצרת בשביעי של פסח ונאמר עצרת בשמיני של חג מה להלן לתשלומין אף כאן לתשלומין
>
> It says “Atzeres” by the seventh day of Pesach, and it says “Atzeres” by the eighth day of Sukkos. Just as there it’s for making it up, so, too, here, it’s for making it up.

After confirming that this is a valid Gezeirah Shavah, the Gemara then discusses how we know this is true by Sukkos itself:

> וחגותם אותו חג לה' שבעת ימים יכול יהא חוגג והולך כל שבעה ת"ל אותו אותו אתה חוגג ואי אתה חוגג כל שבעה אם כן למה נאמר שבעה לתשלומין ומנין שאם לא חג יו"ט הראשון של חג שחוגג והולך את כל הרגל ויום טוב האחרון ת"ל (ויקרא כג, מא) בחדש השביעי תחגו אותו אי בחדש השביעי יכול יהא חוגג והולך החדש כולו ת"ל אותו אותו אתה חוגג ואי אתה חוגג חוצה לו
>
> “And you should celebrate it a celebration to Hashem for seven days.” [Understanding חוגג, celebrate, as a reference to the Karban Chagigah:] I might have thought he brings the Chagigah all seven days - therefore the passuk says “it” - only on it do you bring it, but not all seven. If so, why does it say “seven days”? To make it up. How do I know that if you didn’t bring the Chagigah on the first day of Sukkos that you can bring it all throughout the Regel and even the last day [i.e. Shmini Atzeres]? The passuk says, “In the seventh month shall you celebrate it.” If it’s from “the seventh month,” I might have thought it’s for all of the seventh month; therefore the passuk says, “it” - it do you celebrate, but not separate from it.

In summary, we learn Sukkos from the passuk of וחגותם אותו, and we learn Pesach from a Gezeirah Shavah from Sukkos.

Comment: You can see this is a correct answer as it's how רבינו חננאל learns.

Comment: Except the Mishnah on 9a discusses tashlumin by Sukkot, and then the Gemara asks in setting up the Gezeira Shavah "How do we know this"? Therefore it seems most logical to me to presume the question is how do we know there is Tashlumin on sukkot (answer: we learn it from Pesach). Not to mention, the answer is set up as "Atzeret by Pesach" being "there" and the question "here" is tashlumin by sukkot.

Comment: @Gabriel Ultimately the Gemara does answer how we know the Halacha in the Mishnah, and therefore it begins the discussion with “How do we know?” Whenever the Gemara uses the formulation “We see X by A and we see X by B - just as there Y is true, so too here Y is true” - invariably “there” refers to B and “here” refers to A. While I didn’t see the Rabbeinu Chananel that Danny quotes, I can include it in this post if that would help you - maybe he explains it better.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your assessment of the formulation. It makes more sense that it is parallel: We see X by A and we see X by B; just as Y is true by A, so is Y true by B." Moreover, the second part of the discussion is an alternative proof of the source of tashlumin for sukkot, brought because it comes from a tanna whereas the first came from an amora (see Rashi). If the gemara were really structured that we learn pesach from sukkot, and now how do we know sukkot is the question, we would expect some key word, and not "ותנא מייתי לה מהכא"

Comment: @Gabriel “Here” throughout all of Shas always means the thing we’re trying to prove, not the thing that’s been proven. The line you conclude with literally translates to “our Tanna brings it from here” - meaning, our Tanna, which discusses Sukkos, learns it out from the derashah about to be discussed. Finally, according to the way you’re reading it, what’s the Chiddush of the Gezeirah Shavah when we have וחגותם?

Comment: @DonielF Both Rashi and Steinsaltz read the Gemara's first question as how do we know that Sukkot has tashlumin until Shmini Atzeret. מנהני מילי is universally used as asking for a source for what was stated in the Mishnah (here, that Sukkot has tashlumin).  Please explain why the Gemara would start by asking a question on Pesach's tashlumin with no context when the Mishnah only discusses Sukkot. And as for the having both proofs, sometimes more than one proof is given (see A.Z. 25a...they have a gezeirah shavah but then learn it from the passuk itself).

Comment: I agreed already that מנהני מילי is that it goes through Shmini Atzeres. That question is answered at the very end, with וחגותם.

Comment: @DonielF Ok I have amended my question (see above): what would Rashi say is the source for Tashlumin by Pesach (since he reads the Gemara as I do).

Comment: @Gabriel I still think that my answer fits just fine in Rashi.